# How to validate Empty Textboxes, ComboBox and Date in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have created a form that saves sales data into the database and if the user has not filled all fields, It should either display an error message or just highlight the empty textbox. In my case, I made the textbox be highlighted if empty but some of the textboxes such as the date and two of the combo boxes are not highlighted. If the textbox is not empty then save data which I already did code for saving data to the database. I just don't know how to structure to put the else statement that if the textbox isn't empty then save data. Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/t5keMo.jpg

This is my code:

```
Public Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim txt As Control
    Dim combo As New Control

    '  While 
    For Each txt In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf txt Is TextBox Then
            If txt.Text = "" Then
                txt.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                txt.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each combo In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf combo Is ComboBox Then
            If combo.Text = "" And combo.Text = "" Then
                combo.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                combo.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each Dt In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf Dt Is Date Then
            If Dt.Text = "" Then
                Dt.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Dt.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' End While


End Sub
```

Save data:

```
 Public Sub save_data()
    ' load_table()
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader



    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String

        If (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes?", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            Query = "insert into golden_star.sales (date,brand,size,selling_unit_price,cost_unit_price,quantity,cost_of_goods,profit,total_cost_price) values ('" & DateTimePicker.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & txtSelling.Text & "', '" & txtCostPrice.Text & "', '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', '" & txtTotalSell.Text & "', '" & txtProfit.Text & "',
        '" & txtCp.Text & "')"


            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        MessageBox.Show("Daily Sales Entered Successfully")
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        MysqlConn.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using the right control for the right data type. For example, do not use a TextBox for a DateTimePicker and use an ErrorProvider to indicate if a control has any errors.

Here is a very rudimentary example:

```vb
Private _errorProvider As New ErrorProvider()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' loop over every control in your Panel
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Control)()
        ' wire up the Validated event for the control
        AddHandler ctrl.Validated, Sub(innerSender As Object, innerE As EventArgs)
                                       ' if the control does not have a value in it's Text property, then set an error
                                       Dim validatedControl = DirectCast(innerSender, Control)
                                       Dim validationError = If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validatedControl.Text), "Required", String.Empty)
                                       _errorProvider.SetError(validatedControl, validationError)
                                   End Sub
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim anyErrors = False

    ' loop over the controls and select them to force validation
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Control)()
        ctrl.Select()
        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_errorProvider.GetError(ctrl))) Then
            anyErrors = True
        End If
    Next

    ' if any control has an error, then stop execution of the method
    If (anyErrors) Then
        Return
    End If

    ' if there are not any validation errors, then continue with business logic
End Sub
```